# Remesh option is not showing in blender 2.8

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

i am using blender 2.8.  I am a newbie
when I try remesh object in scuplt mode the remesh option is not present.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! According to the docs, the Remesh feature in sculpt mode has been added in V2.82, so it is not available in V2.80 or earlier. Is there a particular reason why you need to use this version ? It is severly outdated.

Comment: If for some reason you have to stick to a 2.8x version I would recommend to use 2.83 LTS.

Comment: my pc doesn't support 2.81 or higher

Comment: Is there any other tool which can be you used for remeshing

Comment: Try [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes) and [Auto Remesher](https://github.com/huxingyi/autoremesher), Both are free and try to maintain a good mesh topology.

Comment: For *Instant Meshes* there is also an addon [Instant Meshes Remesh](https://blenderartists.org/t/instant-meshes-remesh/1114982) by *knekke* that integrates it into Blender.